# Adding objects together

Tags: java, object, entity, 2d, sprite

In a game that I am creating at the moment I want to make it so that the player holds a gun.

Right now I have the gun and the player as one image and it works but it would be alot better to have the gun and the player as seperate images because right now it looks like the player shots bullet from it's forehead and if I would have the gun as an seperate object it would be easier to make the bullets shot out of the gun. I will also implement a weapon switching system later on so then it will also be easier to have the guns as seperate objects.

The problem is that because I have used an AffineTransform and Vector2d to rotate the player to always face the mouse cursor I can't manage to make it so that it always looks like the player holds the gun. It's more that sometimes the gun is a little inside the player, sometimes it looks fine and sometimes the gun is floating in the air, either infront of the player or at the side of the player.

Is there any easy way that I could make the gun "stick" to a part of the player object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our game we make the sword and shield stick to the appropiate position of the sprite of the player/enemy by  having helpermethods like the ones below:

```
public int getPlayerLeftHand()
public int getPlayerRightHand()
```

And everytime the player is drawn (in our game he always has a shield and sword) his sword/shield is drawn at his right/left hand respectively by calling the above methods. The implementors (player/enemy) decide where their hands are so you don't have to worry at all about whether they are rotated or not, you know that every time you call the method the implementors take care of giving you the correct coordinates, in our case by checking what direction they are facing then displacing the coordinates appropriately.

Alternatively if you want a more OOP approach you could pass the player/enemy to the weapon and let them decide how and where they want to be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You probably "just" need to use the right anchor, for example in [`rotate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29). To make this easier, imagine that the Gun bitmap (or [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html)?) has the same size as the player.

I tried to illustrate that in this drawing:

[image: anchor of a rotation]

The left image is the player, and the right image is the gun. Notice that the gun image has the same dimension as the player image, but is of course almost empty. The red point would be the anchor of the rotation - for example in the center of the image, even though that doesn't matter. If you superimpose the gun on the player and rotate both using the same anchor the gun will always be in the right place.

If you know your linear algebra you can of course also solve this analytically. But I would suggest first getting it to work the way you want, and then exploring more elegant solutions from there. A good quick read I found is this four part [blog post](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/). Part 3 and 4 touches on your question. If you want a more thorough introduction any [linear algebra textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435458869) will do, or you might like this [free online course](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You solve this by accumulating transformation matrices.

First, you have a transformation matrix that positions the player.  Next, you define a matrix that positions the gun in the hand of the untransformed player.  Multiply the two matrices together, and you have one that positions the gun in the hand of the transformed player.

Finally, while you're at it, write a transform matrix that positions a bullet relative to the barrel of the gun.  Multiply all three matrices together, and your bullet is where it belongs.

Your 3d graphics library will have routines to do all this for you.

I have to be blunt though: if you don't already know all this, you may have bitten off more than you can chew.